# What's the recommended way to unit test a single method in a yeoman generator?

Tags: javascript, yeoman-generator

The [doc for yeoman unit testing](http://yeoman.io/authoring/testing.html)  seems to be oriented around *integration testing*, namely running the entire generator and then examining the side effects produced i.e. for the existence of certain files. For this you can use `helpers.run()`.

This is all fine and well, but I also want to be able to *unit test* a single method (or "priority") and test internal states of the generator i.e. internal vars.  I have been able to do this before by using `createGenerator` like so:

```
subAngularGenerator = helpers.createGenerator('webvr-decorator:sub-angular', [
  path.join(__dirname, '../generators/sub-angular')
  ],
  null,
 {'artifacts': artifacts, appName: APP_NAME, userNames: userNames,
 });
```

This has no `RunContext`, but I can usually add enough things to the structure so that it will run.  For instance:

```
   // mixin common class
    _.extend(subAngularGenerator.prototype, require('../lib/common.js'));

    // we need to do this to properly feed in options and args
    subAngularGenerator.initializing();

    // override the artifacts hash
    subAngularGenerator.artifacts = artifacts;

    // call method
    subAngularGenerator._injectDependencies(fp, 'controller', ['service1', 'service2']);
```

Which allows me to test internal state:

```
var fileContents = subAngularGenerator.fs.read(fp);
var regex = /\('MainCtrl', function \(\$scope, service1, service2\)/m;

assert(regex.test(fileContents));
```

This works fine as long as the method is basic javascript, like for/next loops and such.  If the method make use of any 'this' variables, like `this.async()`, I get `'this.async' is not a function`.

```
    initialPrompt: function () {

      var prompts = [];
      var done = this.async(); //if this weren't needed my ut would work
...
```

I can manually add a dummy this.async, but then I go down the rabbit's hole with other errors, like 'no store available':

```
AssertionError: A store parameter is required
  at Object.promptSuggestion.prefillQuestions (node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/util/prompt-suggestion.js:98:3)
  at RunContext.Base.prompt (node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:218:32)
  at RunContext.module.exports.AppBase.extend.prompting.initialPrompt (generators/app/index.js:147:12)
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/test-app.js:158:42)
```

I tried to create a runContext and then add my generator to that:

```
var helpers = require('yeoman-generator').test;
// p.s. is there a better way to get RunContext?
var RunContext = require('../node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/test/run-context');

  before(function (done) {

    appGenerator = helpers.createGenerator('webvr-decorator:app', [
      path.join(__dirname, '../generators/app')
    ],
                                           null,
    appName: APP_NAME, userNames: userNames,
  {});

 app = new RunContext(appGenerator); //add generator to runContext
});

 app.Generator.prompting.initialPrompt(); //gets async not defined
```

But this gets the same problem.

My theory is the problem has to with 'this' contexts.  Normally the method runs with the 'this' context of the entire generator (which has a this.async etc), but when I run the method individually, the 'this' context is just that of the method/function itself (which has no async in its context).  If this is true, then it's really more of a javascript question, and not a yeoman one.

It seems like there should be an easy way to unit test individual methods that depend on the generator context such as calls to this.async.  I referred to [generator-node](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-node) as an example of best practices, but it only appears to be doing integration testing.

Does anyone have any better ideas, or do I need to just keep futzing around with JavaScript techniques?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work, but it's a total hack.  I was able to decorate a `RunContext` with the necessary artifacts, and then using `apply`, I put my generator in the context of the `RunContext`:

```
  var appGenerator;
  var app;

  before(function (done) { 
    // create a generator 
    appGenerator = helpers.createGenerator('webvr-decorator:app', [
      path.join(__dirname, '../generators/app')
    ],
                                           null,
 appName: APP_NAME, userNames: userNames,
                                           {}
                                          );
    // get a RunContext
    app = new RunContext(appGenerator);
    // the following did *not* work -- prompts were not auto-answered
    app.withPrompts({'continue': true, 'artifactsToRename': {'mainCtrl' : 'main'}});

    //add the following functions and hashes from the generator to the RunContext
    app.prompt = appGenerator.prompt;
    app._globalConfig = appGenerator._globalConfig;
    app.env = appGenerator.env;

    // the following two lines are specific to my app only
    app.globals = {};   
    app.globals.MAIN_CTRL = 'main';

    done();
  });

 it('prompting works', function () {
    // Run the generator in the context of RunContext by using js 'call'
    appGenerator.prompting.initialPrompt.call(app);
}
```

I no longer get any 'missing functions' messages, but unfortunately the prompts are not being automatically provided by the unit test, so the method stops waiting for something to feed the prompts.

The big "secret" was to call with `apply` which you can use to override the default `this` context.  I put the generator in the context of the RunContext, which verifies my theory that the problem is about being in the improper context.

I assume there's a much better way to do this and that I'm totally missing something.  But I thought I'd at least document what I had to do to get it to work.  In the end, I moved the variable initialization code from the 'prompting'method, into the 'initializing' method, and since my 'intializing' method has no Yeoman runtime dependencies, I was able to use a simple generator without a RunContext.  But that was just fortuitous in this case.  In the general case, I would still like to find out the proper way to invoke a single method.